# MySQL -> HTML Report, Styled like a Pivot Table

Tags: html, mysql, pivot-table

Ok, I'd like to start off by apologizing (profusely), since this seems to be a common question.  Most of the examples seem to be somewhat similar, as well, but - for the life of me, I **cannot** wrap my brain around how to apply the myriad of quality responses to my specific table.  And, I'm sure it's probably just the easiest thing in the world, what with all the very thorough responses/examples/links to resources with explanations/etc.

So, I suppose I'll just get right to it. The basics:

- We host off-site copies of our clients' backups.
- We need to know how much space they're using.
- We are not at all consistent in Naming Convention, folder vs. disk per client, etc.
- We need to automate a 'report', monthly, with data as follows:

  ```
  -[C.Srv 01]---Size(GB)--Free(%)
  Client 01     [Total]   [AVG]
    Server 01   109.43    25
    Server 02   415.19    25

  WHERE C.Srv = [Specified Cloud Server]
  Clients Get a Total Size(GB) and an Average Free(%)
  ```

My MySQL table is this:

```
#    Name       DataType   Length/Set   Unsigned   Allow NULL   ZeroFill   Default
1.   ID         INT        11                                              AUTO_INCREMENT
2.   Client     TEXT
3.   Server     TEXT
4.   C.Srv      TEXT  
5.   Size       DECIMAL    10,2 
6.   Free       DECIMAL    10,4
```

So, for Example, let's say I have this...

```
___ ________ ________ _________ _________ _______
ID | CLIENT | SERVER | C.SRV   | SIZE    | FREE
---|--------|--------|---------|---------|-------
1  | a      | adc    | cs_01   |  109.43 | 0.2504
2  | a      | asql   | cs_01   |  415.19 | 0.2504
3  | b      | bdc    | cs_01   |  583.91 | 0.1930
4  | b      | bdev   | cs_01   |  316.52 | 0.1930
5  | b      | bsql   | cs_01   | 1259.56 | 0.1930
6  | c      | cdc    | cs_01   |  355.30 | 0.7631
7  | d      | ddc    | cs_01   |  398.21 | 0.5808
```

Is it possible to get something pretty, in HTML (preferably), that has the basic structure of this...

```
 _______ __________ ________
 CS_01  | Size(GB) | Free(%)
 -------|----------|--------
-a      |  524.62  | 25.04%
 -------|----------|--------
   adc  |  109.43  | 25.04%
   asql |  415.19  | 25.04%
-b      | 2178.88  | 19.30%
 -------|----------|--------
   bdc  |  583.91  | 19.30%
   bdev |  316.52  | 19.30%
   bsql | 1259.56  | 19.30%
+c      |  355.30  | 76.31%
 -------|----------|--------
+d      |  398.21  | 58.08%
 _______|__________|________
```

Or, am I just S.O.L.?  Format, I can mess with in CSS, or whatever (I hope), just so long as it's in that basic structure. (I don't know if it matters, but the final goal will be to collapse at the Client Level; in case that somehow factors into the approach/data-gathering.)

Comment: `Is it possible` - of course, but you would need to use some intermediate processing to generate that HTML from the database result, using something like php / ruby / perl / java / etc..

Comment: First and foremost: Thanks for the reply!
Secondly: That's ok - I do not know any of those, per se, but I am not adverse to googling them excessively until I can produce something.

Would there be a specific SQL statement I would need to run, or is that wholly dependent on the type of code that will be used as the intermediary?